# change canvas for wordpress plugin

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins

i am using wordpress to make an online drawing website where the user can login and draw something and publish it and this is done using a plugin calld [drawblog](https://wordpress.org/plugins-wp/drawblog/) now i want to modify this plugin and use a different html canvas such as [harmony](https://github.com/nilium/harmony) but i do not know where to start

this is the code or the post drawing canvas of the plugin

```
<style>
    #drawblog_area * {
        z-index:10000;
        border-spacing:0px;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
    #drawblog_palette *{
        border-spacing:0px;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
    .drawblog_colors{       
        border-spacing:0px;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        line-height:10px;
    }
    .drawblog_pens {
        border:none;
        border-spacing:0px;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
    #drawblog_link{
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    .drawblog_post_canvas, .drawblog_post_canvas:active, .drawblog_post_canvas:focus {
        cursor:url(<?php echo plugins_url();?>/drawblog/icons/pencil.cur), crosshair;
        z-index:10000;
        display:inline;
        border:5px solid #000000;
        border-radius:5px;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        vertical-align:top; 
    }
    .drawblog_post_canvas_erase1, .drawblog_post_canvas_erase1:active, .drawblog_post_canvas_erase1:focus {
        cursor:url(<?php echo plugins_url();?>/drawblog/icons/eraser.cur), crosshair;
        z-index:10000;
        display:inline;
        border:5px solid #000000;
        border-radius:5px;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        vertical-align:top; 
    }

    .drawblog_post_canvas_erase1, .drawblog_post_canvas_erase1:active, .drawblog_post_canvas_erase1:focus {
        cursor:url(<?php echo plugins_url();?>/drawblog/icons/eraser1.cur), crosshair;
        z-index:10000;
        display:inline;
        border:5px solid #000000;
        border-radius:5px;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        vertical-align:top; 
    }
    .drawblog_post_canvas_erase2, .drawblog_post_canvas_erase2:active, .drawblog_post_canvas_erase2:focus {
        cursor:url(<?php echo plugins_url();?>/drawblog/icons/eraser2.cur), crosshair;
        z-index:10000;
        display:inline;
        border:5px solid #000000;
        border-radius:5px;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        vertical-align:top; 
    }
    .drawblog_post_canvas_erase3, .drawblog_post_canvas_erase3:active, .drawblog_post_canvas_erase3:focus {
        cursor:url(<?php echo plugins_url();?>/drawblog/icons/eraser3.cur), crosshair;
        z-index:10000;
        display:inline;
        border:5px solid #000000;
        border-radius:5px;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        vertical-align:top; 
    }
    .drawblog_post_canvas_erase4, .drawblog_post_canvas_erase4:active, .drawblog_post_canvas_erase4:focus {
        cursor:url(<?php echo plugins_url();?>/drawblog/icons/eraser4.cur), crosshair;
        z-index:10000;
        display:inline;
        border:5px solid #000000;
        border-radius:5px;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        vertical-align:top; 
    }   
    .drawblog_post_canvas_erase5, .drawblog_post_canvas_erase5:active, .drawblog_post_canvas_erase5:focus {
        cursor:url(<?php echo plugins_url();?>/drawblog/icons/eraser5.cur), crosshair;
        z-index:10000;
        display:inline;
        border:5px solid #000000;
        border-radius:5px;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        vertical-align:top; 
    }   
</style>
<div id="drawblog_area" style="z-index:100000;">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var colors = new Array("00", "FF");
    var pens = new Array(1,3,5);

    function drawblogBasicPens(){
        for (var i=0; i<colors.length; i++){
            for (var j=0; j<colors.length; j++){
                document.write("<div class='drawblog_colors'>");
                for (var k=0; k<colors.length; k++){
                    var color = colors[i] + colors[j] + colors[k];
                    document.write("<img src='<?php echo plugins_url();?>/drawblog/icons/transparent.png' width=10 height=10 class='drawblog_colors' onclick='drawblogSetColor(\""+color+"\")' style='background-color:#"+color+"; border:0px; cursor:pointer;'>");
                }
                document.write("</div>");
            }
        }
        document.write("<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; line-height:15px; border:none; width:"+(colors.length*10)+"px' width='"+(colors.length*10)+"'><tr><td height='3' style='padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; border:0;'></td></tr>");
        for (var i=1; i<=pens.length; i++){
            document.write("<tr><td class='drawblog_pens' id='penwidthbg"+i+"' style='padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; border:0;'><img src='<?php echo plugins_url();?>/drawblog/icons/penwidth"+i+".png' width='"+((colors.length*10)-2)+"' height='15' onclick='drawblogSetWidth(\""+i+"\")' style='cursor:pointer; margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0;display:inline; line-height:15;background:none' ></td></tr>");
        }
        document.write("</table>");
        document.write("<img src='<?php echo plugins_url();?>/drawblog/icons/pencil.png' onclick='drawblogPencilOn()' style='cursor:pointer' id='pencilbutton'>");
        document.write("<img src='<?php echo plugins_url();?>/drawblog/icons/eraser.png' onclick='drawblogEraserOn()' style='cursor:pointer' id='eraserbutton'>");
        document.write("<img src='<?php echo plugins_url();?>/drawblog/icons/erase_all.png' onclick='drawblogClearAll()' style='cursor:pointer'>");
        if (typeof drawblogButtons == 'function') drawblogButtons();
    }

</script>


<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:0px;padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; border:none;width:40px" width=40 id="drawblog_palette">
    <tr valign="top"><td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top" style="vertical-align:top;padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; ">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (typeof drawblogPremiumPens == 'function') drawblogPremiumPens();
            else drawblogBasicPens();
        </script>           
    </td><td align="left" style='padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; border:none' ><div style="display:inline">
        <canvas id="drawblog_post_canvas" width="<?php echo $width;?>" height="<?php echo $height;?>" class="drawblog_post_canvas"></canvas></div>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><div style="text-align:left"><input type="checkbox" name="drawblog_include_pic" value="true" id="drawblog_include_pic" style="padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; text-align:left; width:15px;" checked> <label for='drawblog_include_pic'>Include this picture with my post. (Unchecking this box will delete anything you've drawn.)</label>
        </div>
    </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="drawblog_picture" id="drawblog_picture">


<script type="text/javascript">
    var browseroffset = 5;
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') browseroffset = 0; // IE doesn't add our border to cursor position

    // initialize the canvas and such
    var drawblogArea = document.getElementById("drawblog_area");
    var drawblogDraw = false;
    var drawblogSize = 1;
    var drawblogColor = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
    var drawblogCanvas = document.getElementById("drawblog_post_canvas");
    var drawblogCtx = drawblogCanvas.getContext("2d");
    var lastx, lasty, offsetx, offsety;
    var drawblogHasDrawn = false;
    var drawmode = 'draw';
    var eraseColor = "rgba(255,255,255,1)"; 
    var pos;

    // paint the canvas white
    drawblogCtx.fillStyle = "white";
    drawblogCtx.fillRect(0,0,<?php echo $width;?>,<?php echo $height;?>);

    // set the pen to black, width to 1 
    var pencil = document.getElementById("pencilbutton");
    pencil.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF33";
    drawblogSetColor("000000");
    drawblogSetWidth(1);
    drawblogCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false); //keeps dragging from changing cursor to text selector in Chrome

    // function time!
    function drawblogEraserOn(){        
        drawmode = 'erase';
        var eraser = document.getElementById("eraserbutton");
        var pencil = document.getElementById("pencilbutton");
        eraser.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF33";
        pencil.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        drawblogCanvas.className = 'drawblog_post_canvas_erase'+drawblogSize;
    }   
    function drawblogPencilOn(){
        drawmode = 'draw';
        var eraser = document.getElementById("eraserbutton");
        var pencil = document.getElementById("pencilbutton");
        eraser.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        pencil.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF33";
        drawblogCtx.fillStyle = drawblogColor;
        drawblogCtx.strokeStyle = drawblogColor;
        drawblogCanvas.className = 'drawblog_post_canvas';
    }
    function drawblogClearAll(){
        var clear = false;
        if (drawblogHasDrawn) {
            if (confirm("<?php echo get_option( 'drawblog_warning2'); ?>")) clear = true;
        } else clear = true;
        if (clear){
            drawblogHasDrawn = false;
            drawblogCtx.fillStyle = "white";
            drawblogCtx.fillRect(0,0,<?php echo $width;?>,<?php echo $height;?>);   
            drawblogCtx.fillStyle = drawblogColor;
            drawblogCtx.strokeStyle = drawblogColor;
        }
    }

    function toggleDrawblogArea(){
        if (drawblogArea.style.display == "block") drawblogArea.style.display = "none";
        else {
            drawblogArea.style.display = "block";
            var include_pic = document.getElementById("drawblog_include_pic");
            include_pic.checked = "checked";
        }           
    }       
    function drawblogSetColor(color){
        var r = color.substr(0,2);
        var g = color.substr(2,2);
        var b = color.substr(4,2);
        var r = parseInt(r, 16);
        var g = parseInt(g, 16);
        var b = parseInt(b, 16);
        drawblogColor = "rgba("+r+", "+g+", "+b+",1)";
        drawblogCtx.fillStyle = drawblogColor;
        drawblogCtx.strokeStyle = drawblogColor;
        drawblogCanvas.style.borderColor = "#"+color;
    }
    function drawblogSetWidth(penwidth){
        drawblogCtx.lineWidth = penwidth;
        drawblogSize = penwidth;
        var penbg;
        for (var i=1; i<=pens.length; i++){
            penbg = document.getElementById("penwidthbg"+i);
            penbg.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        }
        penbg = document.getElementById("penwidthbg"+penwidth);
        penbg.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF33";
        if (drawmode == 'erase') drawblogEraserOn();
    }
    function drawblogPostSubmit(){
        var includePic = document.getElementById("drawblog_include_pic");
        if (includePic.checked) {
        var canvas_image = drawblogCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var drawblog_picture = document.getElementById("drawblog_picture");
        drawblog_picture.value = canvas_image;
        } 
        return true;
    }
    function drawblogFindPos(obj) {
        if (!pos){
            var curleft = curtop = 0;
            if (obj.offsetParent) {
                curleft = obj.offsetLeft;
                curtop = obj.offsetTop;
                while (obj = obj.offsetParent) {
                    curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
                    curtop += obj.offsetTop;
                }
            }
            pos = [curleft,curtop];
        }
    }

    function drawblogInitCanvas(){
        var drawblogDefaultBg = '<?php echo get_option('drawblog_default_bg');?>';
        if (drawblogDefaultBg){
            var imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.onload = function(){
                drawblogCtx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, <?php echo $width;?>,<?php echo $height;?>);
            };
            imageObj.src = '<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';?>' + drawblogDefaultBg;
        }
        drawblogCanvas.addEventListener ("mousedown", function (ev) {
            var x, y;
            drawblogHasDrawn = true;
            drawblogDraw = true;
            if (navigator.userAgent.search('Firefox') != -1){
                drawblogFindPos(drawblogCanvas);
                x = ev.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
                y = ev.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                x -= pos[0];
                x -= browseroffset;
                y -= pos[1];
                y -= browseroffset;
            } else {
                x = ev.offsetX-browseroffset;
                y = ev.offsetY-browseroffset;
            }
            lastx = x;
            lasty = y;
            if (drawmode == 'draw') {
                drawblogCtx.beginPath();
                drawblogCtx.moveTo(x,y);
                drawblogCtx.arc(x, y, Math.ceil(drawblogSize/4), 0, Math.PI*2, true);
                drawblogCtx.closePath();
                drawblogCtx.stroke();
            } else if (drawmode == 'erase'){                
                drawblogCtx.fillStyle = eraseColor;
                drawblogCtx.strokeStyle = eraseColor;           
                drawblogCtx.beginPath();
                drawblogCtx.arc(x + (drawblogSize*3), y + (drawblogSize*3), drawblogSize*3, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
                drawblogCtx.closePath();
                drawblogCtx.fill();
            }
        });
        drawblogCanvas.addEventListener ("mouseup", function (ev) {
            drawblogDraw = false;
        });
        drawblogCanvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function(ev) {
            drawblogDraw = false;
        });
        drawblogCanvas.addEventListener ("mousemove", function (ev) {
            var x, y;
            if (drawblogDraw){
                if (navigator.userAgent.search('Firefox') != -1){
                    drawblogFindPos(drawblogCanvas);
                    x = ev.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
                    y = ev.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                    x -= pos[0];
                    x -= browseroffset;
                    y -= pos[1];
                    y -= browseroffset;
                } else {
                    x = ev.offsetX-browseroffset;
                    y = ev.offsetY-browseroffset;
                }

                if (drawmode == 'draw') {
                    drawblogHasDrawn = true;
                    drawblogCtx.beginPath();
                    drawblogCtx.moveTo(lastx,lasty);
                    drawblogCtx.lineTo(x, y);
                    drawblogCtx.closePath();
                    lastx = x;
                    lasty = y;
                    drawblogCtx.stroke();
                } else if (drawmode == 'erase'){                
                    drawblogCtx.fillStyle = eraseColor;
                    drawblogCtx.strokeStyle = eraseColor;           
                    drawblogCtx.beginPath();
                    drawblogCtx.arc(x + (drawblogSize*3), y + (drawblogSize*3), drawblogSize*3, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
                    drawblogCtx.closePath();
                    drawblogCtx.fill();
                }
            }
        });     
        if (typeof mobileInit == 'function') mobileInit();  
    }

    if (<?php 
            global $image_exists;
            echo $image_exists;
        ?>){
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function(){
            drawblogCtx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        };
        imageObj.src = '<?php 
            global $post;
            echo content_url(). '/drawblog/images/'.drawblog_get_post_image($post->ID)
        ?>';
    }

    var postForm = document.getElementById("post");
    var oldsubmit = postForm.onsubmit;
    postForm.onsubmit = function(){
        var formreturn = true;
        if (oldsubmit) {
            formreturn = oldsubmit(); // just in case some other plugin has a submit override
        }
        if (formreturn) {
            return drawblogPostSubmit();
        } else return false;
    };
    drawblogInitCanvas();
</script><br>
</div>
```

i tried to embed the canvas of harmony using iframe and change the save function of harmony from

```js
function saveToLocalStorage()
{
    localStorage.canvas = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
}
```

to include the submitting function drawblogPostSubmit from the plugin and includ it in the save function of harmony

but that did not work with me.can you help with a way of using a different canvas but with the same plugin?